# Can I add comments to a .netrc file?

Tags: .netrc

I'm using a .netrc file to steamline pushing and pulling code int a git repository. The problem is, I'm using multiple tenants on the same host, with different credentials. I was thinking about commenting out blocs in the .netrc file, depending on which tenant I'm connecting to.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: `man 5 netrc` makes no mention of any comment syntax. Beyond that, you would probably have to either (a) experiment, or (b) look at the source code of the application that uses it

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: What - by just trying every conceivable character sequence?

Answer (score 3):

you could just add a on-purpose error in the host name, so that it doesnt match

Answer (score 1):

No, netrc files do not have comments as alani mentions. You could try to use several netrc files with just one host/tenant config and symlink the one you want to use to `$HOME/.netrc`.